# firebase retrieve data by using equalTo()

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve all car data where name is golf but i get no results:

This is my query:

```swift
ref.child("auto").queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue: "golf").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

my Firebase structure is:

```
-auto

--luhrvuuigvuilthuv

---tgrebytfbyuhbyujvyjb
----name:golf
----age: 2
----color: blue

---funjityvniyyuhntyity
----name:golf
----age: 2
----color: blue
```

Where is the problem? Thnx in advance

Comment: The Firebase Database queries child nodes of the location. The property you filter on must be at a fixed location under that child. And `luhrvuuigvuilthuv` doesn't have a property `name`, so the query doesn't match anything. It looks like you're trying to implement categories, for which I described a good data model here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Comment: Thnx man, luhrvuuigvuilthuv is the userid and tgrebytfbyuhbyujvyjb and funjityvniyyuhntyity are childbyautoid. name property is under childbyautoid, how can i do?

Comment: You'll need to pull up the `name` into a list of `names`. See my answer to the question I linked in the first comment.

Comment: so i have to create in firebase another list when a new car is entered? sorry but i'm new to firebase... thnx anyway

Comment: now i modified my node in this way:

-auto
--sfghsedhsrtr (autoID of the car)
---addedbyuser: sdgergergh
---namecar: golf
---age:2
---color:blue

Now i can make my query i added indexOn namecar

the new problem is that when i want to see all the car from a specific user it shows me but in the output i see that it's better that i indexed addedbyuser and this is impossible...

should i wrote another node like the foldaway and keep both?